# mysql create table using array for field names

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a table using an array for the column names.
the number of columns will vary in the table from 2 to 200 but all columns will be named such as field1 field 2 and so on.
Is what I am trying to do possible because I have not been able to find any examples of such anywhere.

the php would look something like below.

```
$field = array();
While($i<=$numberOfentries){
$field[$i]=$entry[$i];
$i++
}
```

$sql = "(CREATE TABLE '$table' 
     implode($field) *this is where I am stuck*

all column types will be int  2 digits

Comment: You need to specify the columns types as well

Comment: user4035  that was quick, yes that is also part of my problem. Kinda new to mysql still trying to figure it out

Comment: You are missing, among other things, the `TABLE` keyword.  `CREATE TABLE <tablename> (col INT, col2 INT, col3 INT)`

Comment: Why do you need to create tables in runtime?

Comment: Michael Berkowski Thanks Mike I understand that. I just did this quick. I am familliar with the basics of creating a table but when it comes to using string variables for creating a table I am lost

Comment: Question: are you sure you truly want up to 200 columns named field<number>?  Does every row have the same 200 columns?   If not, what about a column for id, a column for fieldname and a column for field value?

Comment: Scott Wilson You're right I would need 1 more column for ID (called Name) . the odds are it will never be 200 but the possibilty is there. The table would only be temporary and deleted after use. It is used for scoring in a tournament and each column would be the game number which will vary depending on number of teams entered in tournament

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $rows looks like this:

```
$rows = array (
    array('name'=>'name', 'type'=>'int not null'),
);
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `mytable` ( ";
foreach ($row as $rows) {
    $sql .= "`{$row['name']}` {$row['type']},";
}
$sql .= ");";
```

Something similar to this should work.

Comment: Chen Asraf Thanks for your response. Would you please explain what "array('name'=>'name', 'type'=>'int not null')," is doing here  ie what is "NAME" ? should that be $field? I still lost!

Comment: It's how I chose to do it, but you can simply have an array of strings like `field1 string not null`or Whatever you choose. Look up the syntax to creating a table and built it however you want.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend to use framewrok CodeIgniter, where already exist implementation of Active Records:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Or use similar classes:

http://www.phpactiverecord.org/

That exactly, what you find.